# Is it possible to only a sub set of internal IP addresses behind a proxy setting to access an Azure instance?

Tags: azure, proxy, firewall

I need to allow a subset of internal IP addresses behind a proxy setting to access an Azure instance.
How to configure the Azure firewall to realize the above-mentioned requirement?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an AD equivalent mechanism in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure your proxy to create local end sockets in a certain range for some IPs and not others then you can impose a rule on Azure’s firewall that applies to the source socket properties too

Example

```
192.168.1.1 is allowed access to the azure facility
192.168.2.1 is not allowed access to the azure facility
```

When 1.1 is using the proxy the proxy will open a connection to azure that originated from a local port in the range 10000 to 11000

When 2.1 is using the proxy the proxy will open a connection to azure that originates from a local port on the range 20000 to 21000

Azure firewall is configured so that it only permits connections where the remote end (from azure’s perspective) is in the range 10000 to 11000

A similar fiddle could use source ips instead of ports. It depends what is possible in your networking setup

Ultimately though you’re really looking at a solution where the proxy should be limiting access. It’s not azure firewall’s responsibility to control what goes on inside your lan